# Convert JPEG to 8bit BMP

Tags: php

I've code which convert into 16bit bmp; I was trying to find out what should be change or add to achive 8 bit bmp file but still nothing. I can only imagine that should be change $bfOffBits

```
<?php
//convert jpeg to 16 bit bmp

$jpgImageFile = 'TEST.jpg';
$newFileName = 'NEW_BMP';


$imageSource = imagecreatefromjpeg($jpgImageFile);
imagebmp($imageSource,$newFileName.".bmp");


function imagebmp(&$im, $filename = "")
{
    if (!$im) return false;
    $w = imagesx($im);
    $h = imagesy($im);
    $result = '';

    if (!imageistruecolor($im)) {
        $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
        imagecopy($tmp, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h);
        imagedestroy($im);
        $im = & $tmp;
    }

    $biBPLine = $w * 2;
    $biStride = ($biBPLine + 3) & ~3;
    $biSizeImage = $biStride * $h;
    $bfOffBits = 66;
    $bfSize = $bfOffBits + $biSizeImage;
    $result .= substr('BM', 0, 2);
    $result .=  pack ('VvvV', $bfSize, 0, 0, $bfOffBits);
    $result .= pack ('VVVvvVVVVVV', 40, $w, '-'.$h, 1, 16, 3, $biSizeImage, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    $numpad = $biStride - $biBPLine;


      $result .= pack('VVV',63488,2016,31);
      for ($y = 0; $y < $h; ++$y) {
        for ($x = 0; $x < $w; ++$x) {

            $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
            $r24 = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g24 = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $b24 = $rgb & 0xFF;
            $col = ((($r24 >> 3) << 11) | (($g24 >> 2) << 5) | ($b24 >> 3));
            $result .= pack('v',$col);
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numpad; ++$i)
            $result .= pack ('C', 0);
    }
    if($filename==""){
    }
    else
    {
        $file = fopen($filename, "wb");
        fwrite($file, $result);
        fclose($file);
    }
    return true;
}
?>
```

**Question**: How it looks like for 8bit?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagetruecolortopalette.php

Comment: Thanks @MarcB but this function use GD library and is for png and gif so this is the wrong way.

Comment: yes, and? You ARE using the gd library. where do you think `imagecreatefromjpeg` comes from? Once you load an image into GD, it's not a gif/jpg/png anymore. It's a GD image.

Comment: Why do you say its currently 16bit it appears to be 24bit (maybe 32)....never mind you have changed the code drastically while I was writing this.

Comment: @Scott previous one was for 24bit, now is correct for 16bit, sorry.

Comment: 24bit and 8 bit are very different - 8 bit usually works off a stored color pallette while 24bit stores an actual RGB value for each color intensity.

Comment: @MarcB unfortunately GD library convert to WBMP, which is for my purpose totally useless. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that I found the answer. I've used imagick library becouse GD library doesn't respond **bmp** format, instead it uses **wbmp** which makes a diffrence.

My code to call imagick:

```
<?php
//convert jpeg to 8 bit bmp with imagick library

//Read the image
$im = new imagick( 'input.jpg' );

// Set number of colors
$numberColors = 256;

// Set colorspace
$colorSpace = Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB;

// Set tree depth
$treeDepth = 0;

// Set dither
$dither = false;

// Set quantize
$im->quantizeImage($numberColors, $colorSpace, $treeDepth, $dither, false);

// write to disk
$im->writeImage( 'output.bmp' );
?>
```